# Fragment Loads webservice before it is visible

Tags: web-services, android-fragments, android-viewpager

***I have three fragments/tabs in viewpager***

My ***first tab*** loads data from webservice when OnCreateView() is called and populates all the child view in fragment e.g i have spinner and edittexts inm it.

When i open ***second tab*** it working find , i'm storing webserice data in siglnton class

when i go to ***third tab*** its fine and i update the data on the server

But problem is if i go back from thrid tab to second tab it calls the first fragment onCreateView() and my all data is reload that i don't want.